# Pandas dataframe errorbar plots separated by category

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, errorbar

So I've tried `seaborn` and `pandas` native plotting features and feel like I'm relegated to using pure `matplotlib` which is a disappointment but this is the problem I currently have.

I have a `pandas` data frame that has x-values in time, y-values in magnitude, and custom error values in a column called uncertainty. I also have a column called Filters. For each filter, I want to plot essentially an error bar plot with **x=time, y=magnitude, yerr = uncertainty**. Here is a sample data (since the real data is proprietary):

```
Image   Filter    Time  Magnitude   Uncertainty
File1   1 micron    0   12.1    0.008
File2   1.5 micron  0   13.4    0.01
File3   1 micron    1   12.9    0.01
File4   1.5 micron  1   13.8    0.013
File5   1 micron    2   14.2    0.014
File6   1.5 micron  2   14.66   0.0155
File7   1 micron    3   15.12   0.017
File8   1.5 micron  3   15.58   0.0185
File9   1 micron    4   16.04   0.02
File10  1.5 micron  4   16.5    0.0215
File11  1 micron    5   16.96   0.023
File12  1.5 micron  5   17.42   0.0245
File13  1 micron    6   17.88   0.026
File14  1.5 micron  6   18.34   0.0275
File15  1 micron    7   18.8    0.029
File16  1.5 micron  7   19.26   0.0305
File17  1 micron    8   19.72   0.032
File18  1.5 micron  8   20.18   0.0335
File19  1 micron    9   20.64   0.035
File20  1.5 micron  9   21.1    0.0365
```

So on a single plot, I would like a series of points with errorbars (based on the uncertainty column) corresponding to that filter (either 1 micron or 1.5 micron).

If I do this in `seaborn` I get the following:

[image: Seaborn's attempt at doing a plot]

I cannot do a map with errorbar (as is commented in the line above) because it claims:

> "ValueError: yerr must be a scalar, the same dimensions as y, or 2xN."

If I try this in `pandas` directly, I get the following:

[image: Pandas attempt at doing this]

Neither of these is what I want. I thought `pandas` and `seaborn` were supposed to alleviate all these issues and make it simpler and easier to do this sort of work without having to do contrived nonsense like reading it into `numpy` genfromtxt, sorting by filter, etc.

Comment: Could you provide a example of what you want? Errors are present on pandas plot, but very small.

Answer (score 1):

This is achieving what you want:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, hue='Filter')
g.map(plt.errorbar, 'Time', 'Magnitude', 'Uncertainty', fmt='o', elinewidth=1, capsize=5, capthick=1)
g.add_legend()
```

[image]

as @FabienP said in his comment, your problem might simply be that your errorbars are too small to see. Do you mean to plot `yerr=Magnitude*Uncertainty`?